# Injecting a an assembly reference /w Mono Cecil does not work

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mono.cecil

I'm currently playing with Mono.Cecil to add an assembly reference into an already compiled assembly.

I'm using this code to add the reference:

```
this.tracerReference = this.module.ImportReference(typeof(Tracer).GetMethod("Trace", new Type[]
            {
                typeof(String)
            }));
```

`Tracer` is a class from another project. Once I'm done with my modifications to the loaded assembly, I'm saving it like this:

```
var newAssemblyName =
                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(this._assemblyPath) + ".modified" + Path.GetExtension(_assemblyPath);
            var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_assemblyPath);
            Console.WriteLine(newAssemblyName);

            module.Write(Path.Join(directory, newAssemblyName));
```

Once I try to run the new dll, I see this:

```
$ dotnet instrospect.TestCli.dll                                                                               
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'instrospect.types, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'instrospect.types, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[1]    4555 abort      dotnet instrospect.TestCli.dll
```

Even though the dll in question, `introspect.types` is in the same directory as `introspectTestCli.dll` it does not find it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I had the same problem .
Have you solved your problem ？

Answer (score 0):

Assembly probing works differently on [dotnet core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/default-probing).

The following sample works as expected once I update the **app.deps.json** file accordingly.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Cecil;
using Mono.Cecil.Cil;

namespace mod
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                DoIt(args[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                using var assemblyToReference = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly("xxx.dll");                

                var assemblyPath = typeof(Program).Assembly.Location;
                using var a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);
                var t = a.MainModule.GetType("mod.Program");
                var m = t.Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "DoIt");

                var il = m.Body.GetILProcessor();

                m.Body.Instructions.Clear();
                
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                var method = assemblyToReference.MainModule.GetType("Class1").Methods.Single(m => m.Name == "Show");
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, a.MainModule.ImportReference(method));
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                a.Write(assemblyPath + ".new");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"New assembly saved to {assemblyPath}.new");

                System.Console.WriteLine("Now you need to:");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"\t1 - Copy xxx.dll to {Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath)}");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"\t2 - Update {Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyPath)}/mod.deps.json");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"\t3 - Delete {assemblyPath}");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"\t4 - Rename {assemblyPath}.new to {assemblyPath}");
                System.Console.WriteLine($"\t5 - Run: dotnet {assemblyPath} 'some string'");
            }
        }

        static void DoIt(string msg)
        {            
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "runtimeTarget": {
      "name": ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0",
      "signature": ""
    },
    "compilationOptions": {},
    "targets": {
      ".NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0": {
        "mod/1.0.0": {
          "dependencies": {
            "Mono.Cecil": "0.11.4",
            "xxx": "1.0.0.0"
          },
          "runtime": {
            "mod.dll": {}
          }
        },
        "Mono.Cecil/0.11.4": {
          "runtime": {
            "lib/netstandard2.0/Mono.Cecil.Mdb.dll": {
              "assemblyVersion": "0.11.4.0",
              "fileVersion": "0.11.4.0"
            },
            "lib/netstandard2.0/Mono.Cecil.Pdb.dll": {
              "assemblyVersion": "0.11.4.0",
              "fileVersion": "0.11.4.0"
            },
            "lib/netstandard2.0/Mono.Cecil.Rocks.dll": {
              "assemblyVersion": "0.11.4.0",
              "fileVersion": "0.11.4.0"
            },
            "lib/netstandard2.0/Mono.Cecil.dll": {
              "assemblyVersion": "0.11.4.0",
              "fileVersion": "0.11.4.0"
            }
          }
        },
        "xxx/1.0.0.0": {
          "runtime": {
            "xxx.dll": {
              "assemblyVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "fileVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "libraries": {
      "mod/1.0.0": {
        "type": "project",
        "serviceable": false,
        "sha512": ""
      },
      "Mono.Cecil/0.11.4": {
        "type": "package",
        "serviceable": true,
        "sha512": "sha512-IC1h5g0NeJGHIUgzM1P82ld57knhP0IcQfrYITDPXlNpMYGUrsG5TxuaWTjaeqDNQMBDNZkB8L0rBnwsY6JHuQ==",
        "path": "mono.cecil/0.11.4",
        "hashPath": "mono.cecil.0.11.4.nupkg.sha512"
      },      
      "xxx/1.0.0.0": {
        "type": "reference",
        "serviceable": false,
        "sha512": ""
      }
    }
  }
```

Notes:

1. **xxx.dll** is a simple assembly, containing a class named **Class1** wit a static method **Show(string)**.
2. The simplest way to figure out the changes needed in the *app.deps.json* file is to manually add a dependency in the project file and compare the generated **app.deps.json** file (I've included the modified deps.json file above. You can simply search for **xxx** and you'll see the places you need to update)